# Как отследить то, что все потоки завершились (Python)

Tags: python, многопоточность

в цикле создаются потоки, и нужно как-то отследить то, что все они закончили свою работу(или ожидать, пока они все не закончат работу), перед тем, как функция снова вызовется.

```py
def some():
    for num, url in enumerate(urls):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=download, args=[num + 1, url])
        thread.start()
while True:
    some()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде как-то так, например:

```
def some():
    threads = []
    for num, url in enumerate(urls):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=download, args=[num + 1, url])
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    return threads

threads = some()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте через `Pool.map`:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool()
results = pool.map(download, enumerate(urls, 1))
print(results)
```

---

**PS.**

Если в `enumerate` вторым параметром передать `1`, то индексация будет с `1`, а не `0`